# How to extend in scss from parent (in case of BEVM)

Tags: css, sass, bem

I try to understand [BEVM](http://www.slideshare.net/Jyaasa/bevm-blockelementvariation-modifier)+SCSS philosophy.

I don't know how to extend `V` from `BE` in this case.

What I want to achieve:

```
.block {
    &__element {
        background-color: black;

        &--variation-a {
          @extend &__element; //won't work
          color: red;
        }

        &--variation-b {
          @extend &__element; //won't work
          color: green;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to avoid:

```
.block {
    &__element {
        background-color: black;

        &--variation-a {
          @extend .block__element; //work but ugly
          color: red;
        }

        &--variation-b {
          @extend .block__element; //work but ugly
          color: green;
        }
    }
}
```

The only way I've found it's to have a kind of `%element { ... }` aside and extends from it, but it's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables. `$b` to store block name and `$e` to store element name.

Sassmeister [demo](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/445e7b2bed5bc320a5c7e2385d568228).

```
.block {
  $b: &;

  &__element {
    $e: #{$b}__element;

    background-color: black;

    &--variation-a {
      @extend #{$e};
      color: red;
    }

    &--variation-b {
      @extend #{$e};
      color: green;
    }
  }
}
```

But it's bad practice to nest element styles by modifier. Modifier must only override styles.